# CodeIgniter multilanguage database

Tags: codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter site in english. Now i want to add another language (italian), only with database, not language files. I have translated all the content and placed it in database, in table fields like name_en, name_it, content_en, content_it,,,, etc. I want the user to select what language want and to navigate on site with the choosing language. I think to do this with sessions,according to language make querys to model functions that corresponds to database fields; and make english default language otherwise. So can anyone tell me how to modify the code in controller, model and view? 
Thnx in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The script is too big to write it here but i can give a guideline.

First read the session class how to store or retrieve the lang

[Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Second, if you use a user table into your db, make a new column for the language.

Before the view is loaded set the user language to the session or else use english.

Then in your views you have to call your language_model, to retrieve the appropriate string.
Note that is not a good practice to access a model from the view directly. 
In such cases you have to use the modular extension.

If you dont care just access the model with

```
$language = $this->session->userdata('language');
echo $this->language_model->fetch_string($language, 'string');
```